# Lambdas in C++ giving a Function to a other Function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to call

```
template <typename FUNC>
int execute ( FUNC )
{
    int a { 5 };
    int b { 8 };
    return FUNC ( a, b );
}
```

with the following line:

```
std::cout << execute ( [] ( int a, int b ){ return a + b;  }) << std::endl;
```

with the following error:

```
error C2661: 'main::<lambda_5994edd6ba73caf12c83e036d510d0d8>::<lambda_5994edd6ba73caf12c83e036d510d0d8>': Keine überladene Funktion akzeptiert 2 Argumente
```

So the question is what am i doing wrong? The error is German but it basically just says that the function doesn't take 2 parameters which it clearly should do

Comment: FUNC is not valid argument to function in this context. Every argument(again, in this context) must consist of type name, and variable name(in case you want to refer to it, which you want 99% of time). Just make your function accept `std::function<void(int, int)>` and you are good to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not how you should call that function. You didn't specify the argument's name. What you tried to do, is to use the type as a function.

Corrected template function is :

```
template <typename FUNC>
int execute ( FUNC f )
{
    int a { 5 };
    int b { 8 };
    return f( a, b );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually calling the function... you're constructing an object of type `FUNC` and returning it, and `FUNC` is not convertible to `int`. What you meant is:

```
template <typename FUNC>
int execute (FUNC&& f)
{
    int a { 5 };
    int b { 8 };
    return f( a, b );
}
```

Or alternatively (originally wrote "better" but that is bad word choice):

```
int execute(std::function<int(int, int)> f)
{
    int a { 5 };
    int b { 8 };
    return f( a, b );
}
```

Comment: Why do you consider `std::function` better than the template parameter? `std::function` has a construction overhead and a type erasure overhead.

Comment: Better is probably the wrong word. There are cases where type erasure is a good thing, and I wanted to just show that that was a possible solution.

Comment: should be `return std::forward<FUNC>(f)( a, b );` in first example

Comment: @PiotrS. You're right of course, technically. But I wonder whether anyone will ever create a practical class with an `operator() &&`. Or do you know of a use-case?

Comment: @Angew consider following use case http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30a70730dc7e85dc , if you ever start treating forwarding-reference as a regular lvalue then you are asking for troubles

Comment: @PiotrS. Yes, but I think the key question is *practical* use-case?

Comment: @Barry what is *impractical* in the code presented?